# Reading words and numbers out of a text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

I am writing a program that reads a text file and adds unique words and numbers to an ArrayList. I used a delimiter for this but I get a NoSuchElementException when I run the program. Is my delimiter wrong or did I make another mistake?

Here is my program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Indexer
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {

      Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("File.txt")).useDelimiter("[.,:;()?!\" \t]+~\\s");
      int totalWordCount = 0;
      ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
      while ((fileScanner.hasNext()) && (!words.contains(fileScanner.next())))
      {
         words.add(fileScanner.next());
         totalWordCount++;
      }
      System.out.println("There are " + totalWordCount + " unique word(s)");
      System.out.println("These words are:");
      System.out.println(words.toString());
      fileScanner.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, you can use tostring or the iterator to show the words:

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
      while ((fileScanner.hasNext())) { 
               words.add(fileScanner.next());
      }
      System.out.println("There are " +  words.size() + " unique word(s)");
      System.out.println("These words are:");
      //System.out.println(words.toString());
      for (Iterator<String> it = words.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
          String f = it.next();
          System.out.println(f);
      }
      fileScanner.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! The iterator helped. I made a few tweaks to it and it worked how I wanted it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use Set instead of List

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
while (fileScanner.hasNext()) { 
      words.add(fileScanner.next());
```

Comment: That gives me an error:
Indexer.java:10: error: incompatible types: ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to Set<String>
      Set<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: my mistake, it should be new HashSet

Comment: I still get a NoSuchElementException when I do that. Was your response supposed to fix my problem or just to improve my code?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the NoSuchElementException is coming from the 2nd fileScanner.next() inside the while loop.

When the last element from the file is reached, it is read from the fileScanner.next() in the while loop condition, resulting in there being no elements remaining when the 2nd fileScanner call is made inside the loop.

One solution could be to call fileScanner.next() once per iteration:

```
  Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("File.txt")).useDelimiter("[.,:;()?!\" \t]+~\\s");
  int totalWordCount = 0;
  Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
  String nextWord;
  while ((fileScanner.hasNext()) && (!words.contains(nextWord = fileScanner.next())))
  {
     words.add(nextWord);
     totalWordCount++;
  }
  System.out.println("There are " + totalWordCount + " unique word(s)");
  System.out.println("These words are:");
  System.out.println(words.toString());
  fileScanner.close();
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. I had a long java code as my input and my output was "There are 1 unique word(s) These words are:" followed by the whole input.

Comment: Oh, I just addressed the NoSuchElementException.  Using the Set instead of List is definitely key as @Pulse9 and mentioned.  The List will store every word instance; while the Set will only store the unique instances.